# Android: Store Data of Radiobuttons

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to develop an app wich consists of different questions and for each 4 possible answers. These questions are separated in differentes pages so when the user goes to the next radioButton the radioButton needs to be empty or with the selected value before. In order to store data I've thought to use Shared Preferences. However the problem is that in the layout there are only 4 radiobuttons and the same layout is always used.

The idea I have is the following one : `android:user=191919191
android:answer1="A"
android:answer2="B"
...
android:answer20="C"`

I dont' know if this will be alright and apart from this I would need to use this information to select the correct radiobutton in each page.
I would appreciate some help, thanks all.

Comment: Persist the data. And regenerate or set selection of radiobuttons dynamically everytime.

Comment: The problem is that how can i to regenerate the radiobuttons everytime?

Comment: Refer this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-radio-buttons/